# STM32 - two-way bus gpio configuring

Tags: stm32, gpio

I need to connect stm32 to a two-way bus. Then I have to read/set bus state (it doesn't matter - using interrupts or not) to get/transmit some pieces of data from the bus. This is a custom bus (8-12 bit).

Is there a way to configure STM32 MCU to read and write states to the GPIO pins?

I've never tried to do that before. Give me a piece of good advice, please.

Comment: You're basically just asking how to use GPIO. This is all in the User Reference Manual. Read and write a bunch of registers.

Comment: @DKNguyen which chapter is it ? Actually, I need GPIO but it must be as an input as well as output simultaneously. I'm not sure that I can easily find it in the reference book.

Comment: It's just the GPIO chapter. Different STM32 lines have different user reference manuals so chapter can vary. "*but it must be as an input as well as output simultaneously.*" That's not possible. One or the other, switched on the fly if need be. But not at the same time. That's the case with most other pins as well. You can build hardware to support weak or strong drive to allow things to be overpowered but the pin itself can only still ever be input or output. You'd have to split the line up to an input and an output with weak/strong drive hardware to read and write the line at the same time.

Comment: @DKNguyen but very old controllers are able to work with a digital bus. Why stm32 can't do this? Are you sure?

Comment: Those pins aren't simultaneous either any more than your PC operating system does things simultaneously. If you want a line to be read and written simultaneously you need to connect both a read and a write pin to that line.

Comment: Take a loon at how ab open-drain bus works

Comment: Thanks, everyone.

Comment: What bus it is? What protocol? How fast? There might be tons of better options than to just bit-bang GPIO.